# ASP.NETCore - Friends System

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, system, social-network-friendship

I`m building an application where I try to make a friend system.

Now, I work with 2 tables for that.
1st: Default AspNetUsers where i store user information.

2nd: Friends Table as below:

```
    public class AspNetFriends
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string friendFrom { get; set; }
    public string friendTo { get; set; }
    public bool isConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

In this table both "friendFrom" and "friendTo" is string type, and receiving the registered users ID.

What i want to achieve is that when i display this table on my view, i want to show the Username of the same UserID thats either in the "friendFrom" or "friendTo" column.

Comment: Okay, so that sounds like a reasonably simple query - have you got as far as trying anything yet? Do you have your database hooked up to .NET, e.g. via Entity Framework?

Comment: Well im pretty new to ASP.NET, im ok in PHP, and i thought that it must be simple, but then i triend a lot of things that haven`t looked ok to me, still trying to figure this one out :)

Comment: If your question is basically "I have no idea how to use a database from ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core" then I'm afraid it's way too broad for Stack Overflow - but there are *lots* of tutorials, guides, screencasts etc. I suggest you start with those - Stack Overflow is for more specific questions.

Comment: (I'd also strongly recommend that you learn about and follow .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your class as followed (I didn't test this):

**Default application user of asp.net core**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace project.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class AspNetFriends
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool isConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser friendFrom { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser friendTo { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get to the getters and setters of the aspnet user

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
{
    var query = from m in _dbContext.AspNetFriends
                    join ff in _dbContext.Users on
                        new { m.friendFrom.Id } equals new { Id = cu.Id }
                    join ft in _dbContext.Users on
                        new { m.friendTo.Id } equals new { Id = cu.Id }
                        where m.ID == id
                        select m;

    return View(query.Single());
 }
```

**View**

```
@model project.AspNetFriends

<p>
@model.friendFrom.UserName
</P>
```

@item.CreationUser.UserName

Comment: If you could share with me the Controller /View also, i will appreciate that :)

Comment: @Ben: changed post